# Salida Grafica para un contador de objetos en python, con datos obtenidos con un sensor en arduino conectado a una raspberry pi

Tags: python, arduino, contador, raspberry

estoy intentando construir un contador de objetos con una raspberry pi 4, obteniendo los datos de un sensor óptico conectado a una placa arduino. Ejecuto este script de python para leer los sensores y contar que funciona en el terminal.

```
import pyfirmata

placa = pyfirmata.Arduino('/dev/ttyACM0')

pyfirmata.util.Iterator(placa).start()

pin2 = placa.get_pin('d:2:i')
pin3 = placa.get_pin('d:3:i')
pin4 = placa.get_pin('d:4:i')
pin5 = placa.get_pin('d:5:i')
pin6 = placa.get_pin('d:6:i')
pin7 = placa.get_pin('d:7:i')


pin2.enable_reporting()
pin3.enable_reporting()
pin4.enable_reporting()
pin5.enable_reporting()
pin6.enable_reporting()
pin7.enable_reporting()


try:

  while True:
    contador6 = 0
    contador2 = 0
    estadoant2 = 0
    estadoant6 =0
    
    while True:
        if pin2.read() != estadoant2: #lee el estado anterior y si es distinto continua 
           if pin2.read() ==1:
              contador2 +=1
              print ("Piezas  procesadas c2: ", contador2)
        estadoant2 = pin2.read() 
        placa.pass_time(0.09)

   
        if pin6.read() != estadoant6: #lee el estado anterior y si es distinto continua 
           if pin6.read() ==1:
              contador6 +=1
              print ("Piezas  procesadas c6: ", contador6)
        estadoant6 = pin6.read() 
        placa.pass_time(0.09)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Terminar programa cuando se presione Ctrl-C.
    pass

finally:
    placa.exit()
```

hasta acá todo funciona ok.
Intento llevarlo más allá para tener una salida grafica pero estoy seguro que estoy haciendo algo muy mal. pues no logro hacer ejecutar la parte de código que cuenta. Si alguien tiene alguna idea u otro punto de vista se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Este es el código con el que estoy intentando la salida gráfica

```
from  tkinter import *
import time
import pyfirmata

placa = pyfirmata.Arduino('/dev/ttyACM0')

pyfirmata.util.Iterator(placa).start()

pin2 = placa.get_pin('d:2:i')
pin3 = placa.get_pin('d:3:i')
pin4 = placa.get_pin('d:4:i')
pin5 = placa.get_pin('d:5:i')
pin6 = placa.get_pin('d:6:i')
pin7 = placa.get_pin('d:7:i')


pin2.enable_reporting()
pin3.enable_reporting()
pin4.enable_reporting()
pin5.enable_reporting()
pin6.enable_reporting()
pin7.enable_reporting()




    
      #FUNCION PARA ACTUALIZAR LA HORA

def times():
     current_time=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") 
     clock.config(text=current_time,bg="black",fg="green",font="Arial 20 bold")
     clock.after(200,times)


global estadoant2
estadoant6 = 0
contador6 = 0
global contador2

def conta():
    estadoant2 = 0
    contador2 = 0  
    while True:
        if pin2.read() != estadoant2: #lee el estado anterior y si es distinto continua 
          if pin2.read() ==1:
             contador2 +=1
             #print ("Piezas  procesadas c2: ", contador2)
        estadoant2 = pin2.read()
        placa.pass_time(0.09) 
        cont.config(text=contador2,bg="black",fg="green",font="Arial 20 bold")
        cont.after(200,times)
        

   


 #VENTANA
root=Tk()
root.geometry("485x250")
root.title("Contador Cepilladora Weinig")
clock=Label(root,font=("times",24,"bold"))

clock.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=25,padx=100)
times()
digi=Label(root,text=" Hora Actual",font="times 12 bold",fg="red")
digi.grid(row=0,column=1)
digi2=Label(root,text=" Piezas Procesadas",font="times 12 bold",fg="red")
digi2.grid(row=0,column=2)

cont=Label(root,font=("times",24,"bold"))
cont.grid(row=2,column=2,pady=25,padx=100)
conta()


root.mainloop()
```

Gracias

Comment: Tienes un sensor óptico conectado al Arduino. El Arduino lee los pines y trapasa esa información al Raspberry Pi. ¿En que parte ejecuta el *driver* del sensor? Los sensores ópticos para Arduino suelen comunicarse vía I2C.

Comment: EL sensor esta conectado al Arduino, la lectura de los pines se hace desde la raspberry gracias al protocolo de firmata que es el codigo que está en el arduino. se leen en este punto pin2 = placa.get_pin('d:2:i')

Comment: Entonces ¿quieres procesar los pines y mantener la interfaz gráfica simultaneamente? Puedes usar asyncio para ejecutar ambas tareas en forma cuasi-paralela. Es una alternativa sencilla y eficiente comparada con threading o multiprocessing.

Comment: Exactamente, quisiera al menos poder leer las variables de contador y mantener la interfaz gráfica. Probaré lo que me comentas. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

He logrado un avance incluyendo la excepción completa. el Problema ahora es que tengo que interrumpir al ciclo del contador para ver el resultado en la ventana grafica. Si no lo interrumpo (ctrl+c en el terminal) no se muestra la ventana-.

El código va así.

```
       import time
       import pyfirmata

placa = pyfirmata.Arduino('/dev/ttyACM0')

pyfirmata.util.Iterator(placa).start()

pin2 = placa.get_pin('d:2:i')
pin3 = placa.get_pin('d:3:i')
pin4 = placa.get_pin('d:4:i')
pin5 = placa.get_pin('d:5:i')
pin6 = placa.get_pin('d:6:i')
pin7 = placa.get_pin('d:7:i')


pin2.enable_reporting()
pin3.enable_reporting()
pin4.enable_reporting()
pin5.enable_reporting()
pin6.enable_reporting()
pin7.enable_reporting()

    
      #FUNCION PARA ACTUALIZAR LA HORA

def times():
     current_time=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") 
     clock.config(text=current_time,bg="black",fg="green",font="Arial 20 bold")
     clock.after(200,times)


global estadoant2
global estadoant6
global contador6
global contador2

def conta():
    try:

        while True:
         contador6 = 0
         contador2 = 0
         estadoant2 = 0
         estadoant6 =0
    
         while True:
              if pin2.read() != estadoant2: #lee el estado anterior y si es distinto continua 
                 if pin2.read() ==1:
                    contador2 +=1
             # print ("Piezas  procesadas c2: ", contador2)
              estadoant2 = pin2.read() 
              placa.pass_time(0.09)

   
              #if pin6.read() != estadoant6: #lee el estado anterior y si es distinto continua 
              #   if pin6.read() ==1:
               #      contador6 +=1
              #print ("Piezas  procesadas c6: ", contador6)
                #estadoant6 = pin6.read() 
              #placa.pass_time(0.09)


    except: 
    # Terminar programa cuando se presione Ctrl-C.
       pass

    finally:
       placa.exit()
       cont.config(text=contador2,bg="black",fg="green",font="Arial 20 bold")
       cont.after(200,times)
      #VENTANA
root=Tk()
root.geometry("485x250")
root.title("Contador Cepilladora Weinig")
clock=Label(root,font=("times",24,"bold"))

clock.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=25,padx=100)
times()
digi=Label(root,text=" Hora Actual",font="times 12 bold",fg="red")
digi.grid(row=0,column=1)
digi2=Label(root,text=" Piezas Procesadas",font="times 12 bold",fg="red")
digi2.grid(row=0,column=2)

cont=Label(root,font=("times",24,"bold"))
cont.grid(row=2,column=2,pady=25,padx=100)
conta()


root.mainloop()
```